# get objectId parse android

Tags: android, parsing

I have done storing into database and but when I wish to retrieve the database elements, I always need to specify the objectID which needs to be checked in database. I want a way by which I can get objectID from the element or better get the object id while storing.

"o1l5gCCPB4" is the objectID

Here is code I used for retrieval:

```
query.getInBackground("o1l5gCCPB4", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if (e == null) {
              String playerName = object.getString("foo");
              tv.setText(playerName);
            } else {
              // something went wrong
                tv.setText("Something went wrong!!");
            }
          }

    });
```

Comment: Is there any way to retrieve an element from Parse database without   knowing objectID?

Answer (score 0):

You can get an element, this way:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(PARSE_CLASS_DRAGS);
    query.whereEqualTo("objectId", objectId);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            //convert the parseObjects to your objects
        }
    });
```

If you want to get all of the elements, you only have to ignore the **query.whereEqualTo()** row.